# Createing SQL view with multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have simple query which works perfectly:

```
(select distinct ACTIVE_MEMBERS, BRANCH_MEMBERS from
    ( select count(*) from pink_floyd pf ) as ACTIVE_MEMBERS,
    ( select count(*) from pink_floyd pf ) as BRANCH_MEMBERS
);
```

And from above query I want to create view - Im doing it like this:

```
create or replace view v_monthly_data AS
select data.active_members, data.branch_members
from (select distinct ACTIVE_MEMBERS, BRANCH_MEMBERS from
    ( select count(*) from pink_floyd pf ) as ACTIVE_MEMBERS,
    ( select count(*) from pink_floyd pf ) as BRANCH_MEMBERS
) as data;
```

But its seems to be incorrect. I would be gratefull for explanation me right way of creating this view.
Also I would prefer not to create multiple views, and then joining them.

Comment: Your two queries are exactly the same, producing the same number of Active and Branch members. Why not just `select count(*) as active_members, count(*) as branch_members from pink_floyd`.

Comment: Can you run the select stand-alone? (I.e. without create view.)

Comment: i mean, you'r right, thats the same queries, but the main point is just to create view. Running query stand alone works fine. I'm struggling a bit with creating view of this query.

Comment: Your simple query is not valid Oracle syntax as `AS` is not a valid keyword before an alias for a table (or an inline view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simple query is not valid Oracle syntax as `AS` is not a valid keyword before an alias for a table (or an inline view). You appear to want to use column aliases and not table aliases.

A correct query would be:

```sql
select distinct ACTIVE_MEMBERS, BRANCH_MEMBERS
from   ( select count(*) as ACTIVE_MEMBERS from pink_floyd pf ),
       ( select count(*) as BRANCH_MEMBERS from pink_floyd pf );
```

Which could be simplified to:

```sql
select count(*) AS active_mambers,
       count(*) AS branch_members
from   pink_floyd;
```

Then you can create a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_monthly_data (active_members, branch_members) AS
select count(*),
       count(*)
from   pink_floyd;
```

or

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_monthly_data AS
select count(*) AS active_members,
       count(*) AS branch_members
from   pink_floyd;
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure why i was struggling so much. It works

Answer (score 1):

You are over4thinking thequery

as both queries return a scalar value you can use them as columns

```
CREATE TABLE pink_floyd (id int)
```

```
create or replace view v_monthly_data AS
select 
    ( select count(*) from pink_floyd pf ) as ACTIVE_MEMBERS,
    ( select count(*) from pink_floyd pf ) as BRANCH_MEMBERS
  FROM DUAL
;
```

```
SELECT * FROM v_monthly_data
```

| ACTIVE_MEMBERS | BRANCH_MEMBERS |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AvJ4h-UU)

In case of multiple return rows you would need something more like

```
CREATE TABLE pink_floyd (id int)
```

```
create or replace view v_monthly_data AS
select AM.count_  ACTIVE_MEMBERS
  , BM.COUNT_  BRANCH_MEMBERS
  FROM
    ( select id, count(*) count_ from pink_floyd pf GROUP BY id) AM
  JOIN 
   ( select id, count(*) count_  from pink_floyd pf GROUP BY id)  BM
ON AM.id = BM.id
```

```
SELECT * FROM v_monthly_data
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5Tfhkfxz)

Comment: You have missed the `FROM` clause in your first query (which works from Oracle 23 but not in any previous versions).

Comment: oracle is still horrible, in some cases, thns